# How to apply two level sorting to a nested list?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, nested-lists

I'm trying to sort the nested list  below based first on first element of each sublist and then based on second element of each sublist.

I'm able to sort based on first element of each sublist

```
from operator import itemgetter

L = [
        [1001, 2513, 894, 631],
        [1001, 4446, 894, 631],
        [1001, 330, 894, 532 ],
        [1001, 1968, 894, 532],
        [70, 2513, 894, 631  ],
        [70, 4446, 894, 631  ],
        [70, 876, 894, 532   ],
        [536, 155, 428, 144  ],
        [70, 155, 428, 144   ],
        [1467, 155, 428, 144 ],
        [1001, 155, 428, 144 ],
        [1629, 111, 265, 41  ],
    ]

Out1 = sorted(L, key=itemgetter(0))

[print(v) for v in Out1]

[70, 2513, 894, 631]
[70, 4446, 894, 631]
[70, 876, 894, 532]
[70, 155, 428, 144]
[536, 155, 428, 144]
[1001, 2513, 894, 631]
[1001, 4446, 894, 631]
[1001, 330, 894, 532]
[1001, 1968, 894, 532]
[1001, 155, 428, 144]
[1467, 155, 428, 144]
[1629, 111, 265, 41]
```

but if I apply the same command to list `Out1` over the second element I don't get the desired output.

My expected output is like this:

```
Out2 = [
        [70, 155, 428, 144    ],
        [70, 876, 894, 532    ],
        [70, 2513, 894, 631   ],
        [70, 4446, 894, 631   ],
        [536, 155, 428, 144   ],
        [1001, 155, 428, 144  ],
        [1001, 330, 894, 532  ],
        [1001, 1968, 894, 532 ],
        [1001, 2513, 894, 631 ],
        [1001, 4446, 894, 631 ],
        [1467, 155, 428, 144  ],
        [1629, 111, 265, 41   ]
    ]
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python sort is stable, but only in regard to elements which have the same value that the list is being sorted on. So when you sort

```
Out2 = sorted(Out1, key=itemgetter(1))
```

It only retains the original sorting of `Out1` where `itemgetter(1)` returns the same value (so you will see that `[70, 2513, 894, 631]` sorts before `[1001, 2513, 894, 631]` in `Out2`).

To sort by the first and then the second value, you need to do so in the reverse order i.e.

```
Out1 = sorted(L, key=itemgetter(1))
Out2 = sorted(Out1, key=itemgetter(0))
print(Out2)
```

or alternatively, sort by both values at once:

```
Out1 = sorted(L, key=itemgetter(0, 1))
print(Out1)
```

In either case the result is as you desire:

```
[
 [70, 155, 428, 144],
 [70, 876, 894, 532],
 [70, 2513, 894, 631],
 [70, 4446, 894, 631],
 [536, 155, 428, 144],
 [1001, 155, 428, 144],
 [1001, 330, 894, 532],
 [1001, 1968, 894, 532],
 [1001, 2513, 894, 631],
 [1001, 4446, 894, 631],
 [1467, 155, 428, 144],
 [1629, 111, 265, 41]
]
```

Comment: @Nick You think yet another trivial one of probably hundreds if not thousands of equivalent trivial sorting questions shows research and is useful? (Because that's what the upvote button is for.)

Comment: @HeapOverflow I just don't think it deserved a downvote. OP does show what they tried (in code and in words). Negatively voted questions do affect people on SO, and I don't think this justified that. Anyway, can we agree to disagree, you've removed your upvote, so I think we're overall even.